# Group which "resembles" the free product of a cyclic group of order two and a cyclic group of order three, but isn't. 

Tags: gr.group-theory

Can someone give an explicit example of a group with two generators $a$, $b$, such that $a^2 = b^3 = 1$ and $a b$ has infinite order, but which is not isomorphic to the free product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: Isn't the free product of $C_2$ and $C_3$ a just-infinite group?

Comment: @Steve No.  The group $\langle a, b | a^2 = b^3 = (ab)^7 \rangle$ is the fundamental group of a closed hyperbolic $2$-orbifold, and is infinite.

Comment: @Richard Are you missing at ``$=1$" in your example? Otherwise I don't think the example you give is a quotient of the group described in the question.

Comment: To perhaps make Mark's answer below a little more explicit: you can quotient your free product by almost any 'sufficiently complicated' element, and you will get another infinite hyperbolic group with the properties you want.  'Sufficiently complicated' means something like 'satisfying a suitable small-cancellation condition'.

Comment: @Todd: have you tried geometric examples, e.g. letting a and b be rotations about two carefully chosen skew lines in R^3?  

Comment: @Peter Oops. Yeah, all those words should be set equal to 1.

Comment: Qiaochu: I haven't thought hard about it. Everyone: it's not that the existence of such things is particularly in question (I fully believe it). But all the examples I've been provided with are handwavy. What I want is a very explicit example, and hopefully a reference. 

Comment: Todd: R. Thompson's group $V$ is pretty specific. Right? But you would need to check the references (Cannon-Floyd-Parry). 

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is straightforward to calculate that the commutator subgroup $G' = D$ of $G = \langle a,b \mid a^2, b^3 \rangle$ is a free group on the generators $x=bab^{-1}a$, $y=b^{-1}aba$, where $|G:D|=6$.

Now $(ab)^6$ is equal to the commutator $x^{-1}yxy^{-1}$, which lies in $D'$ but not in $D''$, so if we add any nontrivial element of $D''$ as an extra relator of $G$, then we will get an example with the required property.

Comment: Wow, this is a really great example; it gives everything I was asking for. Thanks very much! 

Answer (score 22):

The free product $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_3$ (i.e. PSL(2, $\mathbb Z$)) is Gromov-hyperbolic (as every virtually free group) and non-virtually cyclic. Therefore by a result of Olshanskii, "SQ-universality of hyperbolic groups". (Russian)  Mat. Sb.  186  (1995),  no. 8, 119--132;  translation in  Sb. Math.  186  (1995),  no. 8, 1199–1211, it is SQ-universal, that is every countable group embeds into a factor group of PSL(2, $\mathbb Z$). In "most" of these groups (by construction) $ab$ will have infinite order. Thus, in particular, there are uncountably many groups of the type you want.

Update 1: An explicit example would be this. Take $G=PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$, and any word $w(a,b)$ satisfying very small cancelation (that it no subword of length, say, $\frac{1}{10000}|w|$ occurs twice in $w$ (considered as a cyclic word). Then consider the group $G/\langle\langle w\rangle\rangle$. It is what you want. Geometrically, you just kill the large loop in the standard $K(\pi,1)$ for $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ of course.

Another example, as far as I remember, is the R. Thompson group $V$ (it is generated by an element $a$ of order 2 and an element $b$ of order 3 such that $ab$ has infinite order (Mason?). It should be written in the Cannon-Floyd-Parry's survey on Thompson groups, but I do not have it with me.

Update 2: I cannot find the reference to the result about $V$. It is not in Cannon-Floyd-Parry. But here is a paper where it is proved that $SL(n,{\mathbb Z})$ is generated by an element of order 2 and an element of order 3, provided $n\ge 13$: Sanchini, Paolo; Tamburini, M. Chiara, Constructive $(2,3)$-generation: a permutational approach.
Rend. Sem. Mat. Fis. Milano 64 (1994), 141–158 (1996).

Update 3: The paper cited in Update 2 follows this paper: Tamburini, M. Chiara; Wilson, John S.; Gavioli, Norberto On the $(2,3)$-generation of some classical groups. I.  J. Algebra  168  (1994),  no. 1, 353–370. The result there is quite general (and nice), the generating matrices are explicitly given. To check that $ab$ has infinite order, one just needs to find the characteristic polynomial of $ab$ and show that some roots are not roots of unity. That should be straightforward (using any CAS).

Comment: That's very interesting Mark (and thank you), but an explicit example would be very nice. Explicit geometric examples would be most welcome! 

Comment: Does one need the full force of Olshanskii's result?

Comment: @Andreas: No, one can use the fact that PSL(2,Z) is "large" (that is it has finite index free subgroup). Then by an old result of Pride (?) it is SQ-universal. 

Comment: These look like serious contenders in your update, Mark -- thanks very much! I didn't know about Thompson's group $V$, and I would have to do some reading up here to convince myself. But I'm on the verge of accepting this as an answer. 


Comment: Sorry to have to eat my words, Mark. I appreciate the time you put into this, and I wish I could accept your answer as well. But Derek Holt's solution was a bit easier for me to follow. 

Comment: @Todd: No problem. I just wanted to refresh my understanding of the class of (2,3)-groups. 

Answer (score 11):

I don't know an explicit example off hand, but I would recommend looking at the generalized triangle groups

$\langle a,b \ | \ a^2 = b^3 = 1 = w^k \rangle$

where $w$ is a word in $a$ and $b$.  Baumslag, Morgan, and Shalen given conditions on when this virtually surjects $\mathbb{Z}$ or a free group of rank two.  I would suspect that it wouldn't be too tough to find an explicit example where $ab$ has infinite order.

See

Baumslag, Morgan, Shalen, "Generalized triangle groups" Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc. (1987) 102, page 25

and

Fine, Rosenberger, "A note on generalized triangle groups" ABHANDLUNGEN AUS DEM MATHEMATISCHEN SEMINAR DER UNIVERSITÄT HAMBURG
Volume 56, Number 1, 233-244

Comment: Thanks, Richard; that seems very reasonable. I'll see whether I can get hold of that reference. 


Answer (score 0):

I am hazarding a guess, I believe this should do the job

A = {
  {1, x, 0},
  {0, -1, 0},
  {0, y, 1}
 }

It really does not matter what x and y are, they can be chosen arbitrarily and can even be two formal symbols

B = {
  {0, 0, -$i$},
  {$i$, 0, 0},
  {0, 1, 0}
 }

Then A.A= B.B.B = Id

the order of $A.B$ would be infinite when $x$ and $y$ are suitably chosen, for example  one can choose $x$ and $y$ so that the coefficient of the matrices $(A.B)^n$ unbounded ?

Comment: These two matrices may generate a group isomorphic to $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ (at least for some $x,y,\iota$? 

Comment: I am still wondering how to prove that the order of A.B is infinite in a neat way. There must be a way to describe the action in a simple geometric way and conclude .

Comment: Well, I surely believe that you get the desired relations if $x$ and $y$ are algebraically independent, but Mark's objection would still need to be addressed. 

Comment: True. Now, How does one find a relation ? I think I have ended up asking the same question as you originally asked !!

Comment: @Vagabond: In fact they probably always generate $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ if $x,y,\iota$ are sufficiently independent. But see updates 2 and 3 in my answer: there are two matrices of sizes 13 with integer coeff. satisfying $a^2=b^3=1$ that generate the whole $SL(13,\mathbb Z)$. 